# Flutter on Android Studio Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

** How To Fix **

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab.jar (io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\hp.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\flutter_embedding_debug\1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab\ef73898db5174f432ce70c4f440dbc9b669a0dbb\flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab.jar.
> > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\hp.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\flutter_embedding_debug\1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab\ef73898db5174f432ce70c4f440dbc9b669a0dbb\flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: ZipException, message: invalid entry CRC (expected 0x32bac264 but got 0xbd584140). (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
> Suggestions:
> - Check out existing issues at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:460323&s=modified_time:desc, it's possible that this issue has already been filed there.
> - If this issue has not been filed, please report it at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460323 (run with --stacktrace and provide a stack trace if possible).
> Failed to transform kotlinx-coroutines-android-1.5.2.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.2) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.version=6, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.localToProject=public, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=jvm}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\hp.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2b54b6dcea6aabae188cd1d99657079d\transformed\jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-android-1.5.2.jar.
> > zip END header not found
> Failed to transform kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.10) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\hp.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2959e729fdb3a7e5794c11ee213dec94\transformed\jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.10.jar.
> > zip END header not found
> Failed to transform lifecycle-common-java8-2.2.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.2.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\hp.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.lifecycle\lifecycle-common-java8\2.2.0\cd3478503da69b1a7e0319bd2d1389943db9b364\lifecycle-common-java8-2.2.0.jar.
> > zip END header not found
> Failed to transform lifecycle-common-2.2.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.2.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\hp.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.lifecycle\lifecycle-common\2.2.0\4ef09a745007778eef83b92f8f23987a8ea59496\lifecycle-common-2.2.0.jar.
> > zip END header not found

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

This is a gradle issue .

Go to project view and delete all the .gradle and .idea folders and click Invalidate caches and restart from the *File* drop down meny